# scrape movies with beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

hey i want to scrape movies from this site https://www.yidio.com/movies but it only gets 100 movies no more . i found that when scroll down in the browser the html code changes and hidden movies appears it seems like it adds 100 more movies.

i want to scrape 1000 movies at least, how i can do that in beautiful soup?

that's some of my pyhton code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Define the URL of the movie page
list_url = 'https://www.yidio.com/movies'

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(list_url)

# Parse the HTML content using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

# Find all the movie links on the page
movie_links = soup.find_all('a', class_='card movie')

# Extract the movie URLs
urls = [link['href'] for link in movie_links]

movies_info = {
    'Title': [],
    'Genres': [],
    'Cast': [],
    'Director': [],
    'Release Date': [],
    'MPAA Rating': [],
    'Runtime': [],
    'Language': [],
    'IMDB Rating': [],
    'Metascore': []
}


def get_movie_info(url):
    # Send a GET request to the URL
    response = requests.get(url)

    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Parse the HTML content using BeautifulSoup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

        # Extract specific information from the page
        '''
        Extract movie title, genres, cast, director, release date, MPAA rating, runtime, language,
        IMDB rating, meta score
        '''
        # extract title of the movie
        movie_title = soup.find('h1').text.strip().split(' ', 1)[1]
        print('processing movie ' + movie_title + '...')

'''
some other code ...
'''
def main():
    # Iterate over the URLs and scrape movie information
    for url in urls:
        get_movie_info(url)

    # Create a DataFrame from the movie information
    movies_df = pd.DataFrame(movies_info)
    movies_df = movies_df.dropna(subset=['MPAA Rating', 'IMDB Rating', 'Metascore'])
    # Save the movie information to a CSV file with index column and named 'id'
    movies_df.to_csv('movies_info.csv', index_label='id')
    print('==========================================================')
    print('\nMovie information saved to movies_info.csv successfully.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get names and URLs of all movies you can use their pagination API:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd


api_url = 'https://www.yidio.com/redesign/json/browse_results.php'
params = {"type": "movie", "index": "0", "limit": "100"}

all_data = []
for params['index'] in range(0, 1500, 100):   # <-- increase the max index here (0, 100, 200, 300, ...)
    print(f"{params['index']=}")
    data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()
    all_data.extend(data['response'])

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df.tail())
```

Prints:

```
                         name   type      id                                                     url                                                   image
1495                  Sabrina  movie   14361               https://www.yidio.com/movie/sabrina/14361   //cfm.yidio.com/images/movie/14361/poster-193x290.jpg
1496  When Harry Met Sally...  movie   11237  https://www.yidio.com/movie/when-harry-met-sally/11237   //cfm.yidio.com/images/movie/11237/poster-193x290.jpg
1497              Roll Bounce  movie   23861           https://www.yidio.com/movie/roll-bounce/23861   //cfm.yidio.com/images/movie/23861/poster-193x290.jpg
1498              The Holiday  movie   24956           https://www.yidio.com/movie/the-holiday/24956   //cfm.yidio.com/images/movie/24956/poster-193x290.jpg
1499               Juneteenth  movie  229233           https://www.yidio.com/movie/juneteenth/229233  //cfm.yidio.com/images/movie/229233/poster-193x290.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you it really works but can you explain how you did get this url and what is pagination API please?

Comment: @TaharJaafer When you open web developer tools in your browser and click on Network Tab and start scrolling down, you will see this pagination URL there. The page is making these requests to load more pages from server.